# Trustworthy voting system using CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress

TLDR: Is it possible to use CiviCRM as a trustworthy voting system?

In my organisation we need to do votes (changing bylaws, regulations, electing functionaries etc) and I am researching possibility to use CiviCRM for that. We use CiviCRM 5.36 on WordPress 5.7.2.

I have tried:

1. CiviCampaign - Survey: no way, it is for offline use, we need online
2. CiviCampaign - Petition: I eventually could publish a petition in a WordPress page that is visible only for members (WP users automatically synchronized with CiviCRM members using WP plugin "CiviCRM Member Sync"; page accessibility is managed by the WP plugin "Groups"), that could work, but the problem is that a CiviCRM admin can easily change vote of a member, what we do not want...
3. CiviCRM extension Elections: works only for elections of people for elected functions, not for general voting

Now I am considering some WordPress plugin or standalone voting web application, but before that - do you know of some way how now use CiviCRM as trusted voting platform?

Should:

1. no need to manually synchronize membership status / list of members

Could:

1. no need to create new pages in WP for new votings

In case it is not possible directly using CiviCRM, it would help at least to have automatic synchronization of membership status from CiviCRM (aka integration with WordPress).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you would create anything that an admin (or anyone with access to the database) could not change.  Perhaps this could work: create an "event" and put the voting fields in the profile used for that event.  You could use some of the existing extensions to allow only members to register/vote for that "event."  The confirmation sent to the "voter" could be bcc'd to others for confirmation/verification/audit purposes.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation about impossibility of protection against changes by admins!

Finally I have used Petition. To protect the "petition" from misvoting public I have removed from anonymous users the permission to view petitions.